# django-summernote attach images from another model/ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, summernote

I've added django-summernote to a project, but when the user inserts an image, instead of the upload popup, I want a popup with a ModelChoiceField for Photos.objects. It's a website for a photographer, and the Photos model has necessary additional functionality. I could have him go through the process of getting the image's url and adding it that way, but this would be much cleaner.

I've tried a lot of things, but kind of a stab in the dark all around. django-summernote docs describe how to set a custom attachment model, but only just....

First, I created another model in django-summernote.models that inherits from AbstractAttachment:

```
class PhotoAttachment(AbstractAttachment):
  img = models.ForeignKey(Photos, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default='None')
```

I also tried changing django-summernote.forms.py:

from:

```
file = forms.ImageField(required=True)
```

to:

```
img = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Photos.objects, required=True)
```

...and a few other things. I've been poking around for a few hours, but I honestly don't know where to begin. I do have working ModelChoiceFields on ForeignKey's elsewhere in my models coming up in the old djangoadmin, so that's all fine - I just want to customize summernote to pull one up when the user tries to add an image. Suggestions?